# R - Getting Imputed Missing Values back into dataframe

Tags: r, imputation, hmisc

I'm using [aregImpute](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/4.0-2/topics/aregImpute) to impute missing values on a R dataframe (bn_df).

The code is this:

```
library(Hmisc)
impute_arg <- aregImpute(~ TI_Perc + AS_Perc + 
                         CD_Perc + CA_Perc + FP_Perc, 
                         data = bn_df, n.impute = 5)
```

It works fine.

The problem is after. In putting the values back into the original dataframe.

I can do it, just not in a very elegant way. I basically have to copy/paste the following line for all columns:

```
bn_df$CD_Perc[impute_arg$na$CD_Perc] <- impute_arg$imputed$CD_Perc[,1]
bn_df$FP_Perc[impute_arg$na$FP_Perc] <- impute_arg$imputed$FP_Perc[,1]
...
```

This works. But there has to be a more efficient way to accomplish this without copy/paste for all columns.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use function `impute.transcan`. Since you have not provided the data, I have copied an example from `aregImpute`'s documentation.

```
# The data
x1 <- factor(sample(c('a','b','c'),1000,TRUE))
x2 <- (x1=='b') + 3*(x1=='c') + rnorm(1000,0,2)
x3 <- rnorm(1000)
y  <- x2 + 1*(x1=='c') + .2*x3 + rnorm(1000,0,2)
orig.x1 <- x1[1:250]
orig.x2 <- x2[251:350]

# Insert NAs
x1[1:250] <- NA
x2[251:350] <- NA

# Create a data frame 
d <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)
# Find value of nk that yields best validating imputation models
# tlinear=FALSE means to not force the target variable to be linear

# Use imputation 
f <- aregImpute(~y + x1 + x2 + x3, nk=c(0,3:5), tlinear=FALSE,
                data=d, B=10) # normally B=75

# Get the imputed values
imputed <-impute.transcan(f, data=d, imputation=1, list.out=TRUE, pr=FALSE, check=FALSE)

# convert the list to the database
imputed.data <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,imputed))

# arrange the columns accordingly
imputed.data <- imputed.data[, colnames(d), drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. Indeed I probably skipped that function.

Comment: Is there any way we can replace value with average of multiple imputations rather than any specific number (imputation=1)?

Answer (score 0):

The method above only applies the results of the first imputation; in this example you did 5 imputations. In essence, you are doing single imputation, not multiple imputation when you pull only one set of results. Single imputation will upwardly bias correlations and underestimate variability, leading to false positives. Simply averaging results is problematic as well, described below. Using the example data from @discipulus I demonstrate that the return values are only the first imputation as mentioned by @Sourabh in the comments. Instead, we must use Rubin's rules, as described in *Flexible Imputation of Missing Data 2nd Edition* by Stef van Buuren.

```
# The data
x1 <- factor(sample(c('a','b','c'),1000,TRUE))
x2 <- (x1=='b') + 3*(x1=='c') + rnorm(1000,0,2)
x3 <- rnorm(1000)
y  <- x2 + 1*(x1=='c') + .2*x3 + rnorm(1000,0,2)
orig.x1 <- x1[1:250]
orig.x2 <- x2[251:350]

# Insert NAs
x1[1:250] <- NA
x2[251:350] <- NA

# Use imputation 
f <- aregImpute(~y + x1 + x2 + x3, nk=c(0,3:5), tlinear=FALSE,
                data=d, B=10) # normally B=75
```

aregImpute will output, among other things, a list of dataframes, each dataframe with the imputed values for each variable. In this case, x3 and y are not missing any variables, so they will be blank. I will use x2 for the sake of example. Note the first missing value is at position 251; the transcran method shown by @discipulus will return all values, not just those that were imputed, so for this example I chose the first 10 of the imputed values. Also note that all imputed values in the transcran method will be displayed with an asterisk *.

```
# Get the imputed values using transcran method
cran_imputed <-impute.transcan(f, data=d,imputation=1,list.out=TRUE
                               ,pr=FALSE,check=FALSE)
#Display selected transcran output
cranimputed$x2[251:260]

[1] -2.3329168*  1.5932600* -3.6282922*  3.2422261* -1.3834603*  1.2875239*  
0.5626570*  4.7295623*  5.5481088* -0.9608138*

#Display selected aregImpute output
head(f$imputed$x2,10)
      [,1]       [,2]        [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
251 -2.3329168 -0.6594654  2.80066807  0.299462 -0.7277302
252  1.5932600 -0.9454129  1.05948930  2.937997 -0.8695105
253 -3.6282922 -2.8645933 -2.38090446 -3.594926 -4.1508115
254  3.2422261 -0.5999240  1.75537768  1.361398 -0.3312262
255 -1.3834603 -1.8625728 -0.09100125  1.570425 -0.6390260
256  1.2875239  2.5559325  2.61486513  3.271305  2.0244955
257  0.5626570  2.2357555  2.63359835  1.205556  1.1619793
258  4.7295623  2.1502098  2.21818670  4.819109  2.9049529
259  5.5481088  4.2867891  5.71605488  6.493454  7.6569080
260 -0.9608138 -0.5309543 -2.26845321  2.388380  1.2137664
```

Note the transcran results are identical to the first column of the imputation results from the aregImpute method. By altering 'imputation=' in the transcran call, you can select different columns of the imputation and could use this method to generate a dataframe for each imputation and save it.

### Preparing Data for Pooled Analyses

Another option for saving data is concatenating each dataframe into long form as is often done when imputing using the mice package. Essentially, each of the 5 dataframes is stacked atop the other with a new column denoting which imputation each dataframe came from. In this example, the outputted dataframe would be 5000 rows long. I believe this is the format used in SPSS as well.

A few different methods can be used to analyze these data once you generate your 5 datasets. In general, the imputation workflow is to impute the data, validate the imputations, perform whatever statistical tests are being done (correlations, linear regression, etc) on each dataset, then pool the results of those analyses. You will not have one single dataset to work from. Simply averaging all of the multiple regressions together and pretending you have one complete dataset is incorrect and "yeilds incorrect standard errors, confidence intervals, and p-values" (van Buuren).

There are many different workflows for analyzing interpolated data as described in Flexible Imputation of Missing Data chapter 5.1 using the mice package. For linear regression you can also use fit.mult.impute from Hmisc. I think the best thing to do in your situation might be to concatenate the aregImpute results into the long form used by mice, then you can use mice packages to do the analyses you want to do in the first place and pool the results. [This](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/data-analysis-after-multiple-imputation.html) resource provides resources on how to do several pooled analyses. In this case, we will do linear regression.

```
 #Using dataset d as above
 #Use imputation 
 impnum=5 #general rule of thumb is number of imputations=100-%complete cases 
 #Using d, do imputation 
 f <- aregImpute(~y + x1 + x2 + x3, nk=c(0,3:5), tlinear=FALSE,
                 data=d, n.impute=impnum) 

 #Create a dataframe equivalent to mice long form
 long_df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(colnames(d))+2,nrow=0)) 
 #will need one column for each variable in your dataset, plus .imp and .id to
 label imputation number and subject ID
 colnames(long_df) <- append(c('.imp','.id'),colnames(d)) 

 #Generate a dataframe for each imputation i
 for (i in 1:impnum){ #please excuse the for loop... I'm used to Python
     # Using @discipulus' answer above
     # Get the imputed values for imputation number i 
     imputed <-impute.transcan(f, data=d, imputation=i, list.out=TRUE,
               pr=FALSE, check=FALSE)
     # convert the list to the database
     imputed.data <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,imputed))
     # arrange the columns accordingly
     imputed.data <- imputed.data[, colnames(d), drop = FALSE]
     # Create column for imputation number titled '.imp'
     .imp <- rep(i,each=nrow(d))
     #Create column for subject id
    .id <- c(1:nrow(d))
    #concatenate new columns to imputed.data
    imputed.data <- cbind(.imp,.id,imputed.data)
    #concatenate data from this imputation to the longform
    long_df <-rbind(long_df,imputed.data)
 }
 #need to store original data as the first part of the long df for saving as 
 .mids format
 .imp <- rep(0,each=nrow(d)) #original data coded as imputation 0
 .id <- c(1:nrow(d))
 top <- cbind(.imp,.id,d)
 #aregImpute changes categorical entries to numbers in output; will need to 
 convert string levels to intigers
 #can check which levels are used via f$cat.levels; in this case we know only 
 x1 is categorical
 levels <- f$cat.levels$x1
 #will map strings to numbers; note it may be cleaner to change letters to 
 numeric labels before running imputation
 new_levels <- c(1:length(levels))
 top$x1 <- new_levels[as.factor(top$x1)]
 long_df <- rbind(top,long_df)
 #Example-- linear regression
 library(mice)
 #Convert long_df to mids form for use with mice pooling functions
 long_df <- as.mids(long_df)
 #Do linear regression
 lm <- with(long_df,lm(y~x1+x2+x3))
 #Display pooled linear regression results
 pool(lm)
```